# =INDEX(PeriodList,MonthNo) creating _xlfn.SINGLE name in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I hope someone will be able to help with a problem that has surfaced with a recent Excel update.

If I define two range names in an Excel worksheet and then enter =Index(PeriodList,MonthNo) in cell A13 via the UI, I find that Thisworkbook.Names.Count in VBA reports 2 - as expected. However, if I execute Activesheet.Range("A13").Formula = "=Index(PeriodList,MonthNo)" in VBA, Thisworkbook.Names.Count reports 3 and I find that a new name that cannot be deleted is created. The name is _xlfn.SINGLE. The existence of this name is a problem for a significant number of widely distributed Excel templates that fail when attempting to delete this name. This only became a problem after a recent Excel update.

The problem seems to be with the MonthNo element in that "=Index(PeriodList,1)" does not generate the _xlfn.SINGLE name.

Can anyone identify how to enter something that is the equivalent of "=Index(PeriodList,MonthNo)" in VBA without creating the unwelcome _xlfn.SINGLE name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much further investigation I came upon the note at https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd which indicates that the formula now needs to be array entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Now the _xlfn.SINGLE name is no longer created. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

If the function has worked for you in the past and has only recently become an issue, you should check with your IT department as it points to a problem with the version of Excel being used.

_xlfn.SINGLE is displayed for dynamic array functions when they are not supported by the version of Excel that is running.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/issue-an-xlfn-prefix-is-displayed-in-front-of-a-formula-882f1ef7-68fb-4fcd-8d54-9fbb77fd5025

There are many dynamic array VBA solutions available such as here.
https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/dynamic-size.htm

Use this code to display all defined names in the UI Names Manager.  Then you can delete the named ranges of your choice, including those that were previously hidden.

```
Sub ShowAllDefinedNames()

'Source: https://professor-excel.com/named-ranges-excel-hidden-names/

        Dim tempName As Variant

        'Unhide all names in the currently open Excel file

        For Each tempName In ActiveWorkbook.Names

            tempName.Visible = True

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. I have discovered that, even though I can delete the name through the UI when it is made visible, I still can't delete it using `Activeworkbook.Names("_xlfn.SINGLE").Delete` Moreover, even if I delete the name using the UI, when the file is saved and re-opened the name is there again. I opened a VBA created file, created in May 2015 with Excel 2003, and found that the "_xlfn.SINGLE" name is there too! As I'm using 32 bit Office 2016 version 1910 (Build 12130.20410), which supports the INDEX function, I'm not sure your second paragraph is relevant.